# MVC form validation without form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a standard form populated by an MVC model with standard [Required] validation. I want to "submit" this form data via AJAX, not by a submit, and I would like to take advantage of the built-in MVC/razor validation features. I can't figure out how to fire the client-side validation without triggering the form submit event.

Here is my razor markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     <span class="label">Team Name:</span>&nbsp;@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
```

And here is my model:

```
public class Team
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

It seems like this should be an easy thing to do. It works beautifully on submit. I just need to know how to invoke the validation method manually.

Comment: [See this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors#errors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is enabled by default, but it has not been working because you might not have added links to the required JavaScript libraries.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It possible that you are getting the server side validation. If you don't have the jquery.validate scripts, you will not get client side validation. $('form').submit() should trigger the client side validation too.

Comment: ugh, I should have known, it was this easy. All my forms that I submit have these libraries; those that are submitted via Ajax, were missing them... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the top answer, when you google for "mvc validation form submit" I have to add another point, which coast me a few hours. When you are using

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

in your code, the form get's submited, even if you added these libraries and set

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in the appSettings property of your webconfig.